# Why sending data from gpu to cpu is slower than cpu to gpu?

Tags: gpu, data-structure

Why sending data from gpu to cpu is slower than cpu to gpu?

I heard the relation is similar to network situation, in detail, the upload is slower than download. However, I could not understand the meaning.

In my opinion,  the sending operation should be same because the two sending buses (cpu to gpu and gpu to cpu) can be made with the same performance (I mean bendwith).

Comment: What makes you think it is necessarily slower? If you can [edit] your question to add that extra detail, you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual sending of data is the same. The PCIe bus is the same speed in both directions.

However when programming there is a big difference namely that when you send you can immediately start doing something else (including queuing other operations using that new data) while the actual transfer is going on. But when receiving you need to synchronize on the completion of the transfer before you can use the data that was sent.

Comment: That's not exactly accurate, though. Commands that actually send data to the API are *still* synchronous, e.g. you can immediately free the memory that you called `glBufferData` with right after calling it, since it's copied into the API then. What *is* possibly unsynchronized is the transfer of that data to the actual GPU memory. However, the same asynchronous transfer approaches can be applied for data download, too. It's just that in this case you usually have to wait for all previous operations to finish.

Comment: @ChristianRau but most of the time the data you send through glBufferData is first copied to another part of memory from which the actual transfer to the GPU will take place asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah, but you could as well do that with `glReadPixels`.

Comment: @ChristianRau no because the driver cannot know you want that data until you call glReadPixels which is the trigger to make the gpu start sending data to RAM. The glReadPixels call cannot return until the GPU is done and the data is ready to be used.

Comment: No, `glReadPixels` *will* return immediately if you tell it to copy that data into a buffer object. Then you can do other things and *then* you can retrieve the data from the buffer whenever you want.

Comment: @ChristianRau oh you were using `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`, yeah that will let you do transfers async (though you have to assume the driver isn't dumb enough to leave that in vram)